# How to calculate how much storage a CSV will use when uploaded to SObject

Tags: sobject, csv, import

So I have a .csv file that contains ~12,000 rows and on my local filesystem takes up about 3MB of data. I assumed that when I imported this csv into a Salesforce Object, the data would still take up around 3MB of space, however it ends up taking over 25MB of space.

I'm trying to figure out what causes the discrepancy between storage sizes (I assume that there are some metadata files that get created and are counted agains the org limits, however an extra 22MB of data seems unnecessary). Does anyone know what causes this and/or how I could accurately predict how much Salesforce storage a CSV file would consume before importing it into an SObject?

Thank you!

The CSV File in my File System:

[image]

The Size of the Data once imported into an SObject:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each SObject record in Salesforce consumes a flat 2kB of your "Data" limit, regardless of how much (or how little) actual data it contains. Everyone gets a base 10GB of "Data" storage, with an additional 20MB per regular user license<sup>1</sup> (so this doesn't count "free chatter users" and the like)

12,969 records * 2kB = 25.938MB Data space used

The notable exception to this is the `TextBody` and `HtmlBody` fields of the `EmailMessage` SObject, which consume 2kB (for the base SObject record) + every single bit in those two fields. There are a few other objects that go above 2kB, as documented in [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383664&type=1)

Reproduced here

| SObject | "Data" storage used |
| --- | --- |
| Leads | 2KB |
| Contacts | 2KB |
| Accounts | 2KB |
| Person Accounts | 4KB |
| Opportunities | 2KB |
| Forecasts | 2KB |
| Events | 2KB |
| Tasks | 2KB |
| Cases | 2KB |
| Case Team Member | 2KB |
| Solutions | 2KB |
| Notes | 2KB |
| Custom Reports | 2KB |
| Campaigns | 8KB |
| Campaign Members | 1KB |
| Contracts | 2KB |
| Google Docs | 2KB |
| Quotes | 2KB |
| Quote Line Items | 2KB**** |
| Orders | 2KB**** |
| Work Order Line Items | 2KB**** |
| Tags: unique tags | 2KB |
| Custom Objects | 2KB |
| Quote Template Rich Text Data | 2KB |
| Articles | 4KB* |
| Email Message | 2KB** |
| Person Accounts | 4KB*** |

<sup>1: 20MB for Contact Manager, Group, Professional, and Enterprise editions. 120MB for Performance and Unlimited editions.</sup>

Comment: Ah that is good to know, I had no idea! Thank you so much.